# Reading from another child element using Elementree

Tags: python, pandas, elementtree

The code below goes through the xml files and parses them into a single csv file

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
from pathlib import Path

directory = 'path to a folder with xml files'

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    headers = ['id', 'service_code', 'rational', 'qualify', 'description_num', 'description_txt', 'set_data_xin', 'set_data_xax', 'set_data_value', 'set_data_x']
    writer.writerow(headers)

    xml_files_list = list(map(str, Path(directory).glob('**/*.xml')))
    print(xml_files_list)
    for xml_file in xml_files_list:
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()

        start_nodes = root.findall('.//START')
        for sn in start_nodes:
            row = defaultdict(str)

            repeated_values = dict()
            for k,v in sn.attrib.items():
                repeated_values[k] = v

            for rn in sn.findall('.//Rational'):
                repeated_values['rational'] = rn.text

            for qu in sn.findall('.//Qualify'):
                repeated_values['qualify'] = qu.text

            for ds in sn.findall('.//Description'):
                repeated_values['description_txt'] = ds.text
                repeated_values['description_num'] = ds.attrib['num']

            for st in sn.findall('.//SetData'):
                for k,v in st.attrib.items():
                    row['set_data_'+ str(k)] = v
                for key in repeated_values.keys():
                    row[key] = repeated_values[key]
                row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]
                writer.writerow(row_data)
                row = defaultdict(str)
```

This is the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectData>
 <Phones>
    <Date />
    <Prog />
    <Box />
    <Feature />
    <IN>MAFWDS</IN>
    <Set>234234</Set>
    <Pr>23423</Pr>
    <Number>afasfhrtv</Number>
    <Simple>dfasd</Simple>
    <Nr />
    <Get>6070106091</Get>
    <Reno>1233</Reno>
  </Phones>
<FINAL>
    <START id="B001" service_code="0x5196">
      <Docs Docs_type="START">
        <Rational>225196</Rational>
        <Qualify>6251960000A0DE</Qualify>
      </Docs>
      <Description num="1213f2312">The parameter</Description>
      <DataFile dg="12" dg_id="let">
        <SetData value="32" />
      </DataFile>
    </START>
    <START id="C003" service_code="0x517B">
      <Docs Docs_type="START">
        <Rational>23423</Rational>
        <Qualify>342342</Qualify>
      </Docs>
      <Description num="3423423f3423">The third</Description>
      <DataFile dg="55" dg_id="big">
        <SetData x="E1" value="21259" />
        <SetData x="E2" value="02" />
      </DataFile>
    </START>
    <START id="Z048" service_code="0x5198">
      <RawData rawdata_type="ASDS">
        <Rational>225198</Rational>
        <Qualify>343243324234234</Qualify>
      </RawData>
      <Description num="434234234">The forth</Description>
      <DataFile unit="21" unit_id="FEDS">
        <FileX unit="eg" discrete="false" axis_pts="19" name="Vsome" text_id="bx5" unit_id="GDFSD" />
        <SetData xin="5" xax="233" value="323" />
        <SetData xin="123" xax="77" value="555" />
        <SetData xin="17" xax="65" value="23" />
      </DataFile>
    </START>
</FINAL>
</ProjectData>
```

This is how the output looks like

[image]

Currently struggling to modify the code , so it goes to  **Phones** (which is another child of Projectdata) takes  elements from **Set** and **Get**  attaches them together with **_** and parses them into the first column  that has the header names ** Identify**
The picture bellow shows how It should look.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `headers` line to

```
headers = ['identify', 'id', 'service_code', 'rational', 'qualify', 'description_num', 'description_txt', 'set_data_xin', 'set_data_xax', 'set_data_value', 'set_data_x']
```

```
p_get = tree.find('.//Phones/Get').text
p_set = tree.find('.//Phones/Set').text
```

and add this info to the `row_data` just before the line `writer.writerow(row_data)`

like this:

```
row_data.insert(0, p_get + '_' + p_set)
```

**Update**

```
row_data[0] = p_get + '_' + p_set
```

Comment: I add  _row_data.insert(0, p_get + '_' + p_set)_  just before writer.writerow(headers)  . what about p_get = tree.find('.//Phones/Get').text
 where should I paste these two

Comment: can you please help me on where I have to add the lines? I don't have row_data anywhere declared

Comment: @ebe add `pget = ...` and `p_set = ...` just after `root = tree.getroot()` and `row_data.insert( ... )` after `row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]`

Comment: @Valentino, where should I add **row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]** though ?

Comment: @Valentino, as I added  identify to the header, the next column is empty and everything else is shifted by one column. It can be seen on the output  https://pasteboard.co/IPKPldQ.png

Comment: @abhilb, Could you please have a look at how my output is looking. Column Id is empty and everything else is shifted.   Would really appreciate the help  https://pasteboard.co/IPKPldQ.png

Comment: @abhilb, Please have a look at the picture in the above comment.

Comment: If I add the header identify at last and then modify this into **row_data.insert(26, p_get + '_' + p_set). this works fine but I want to have identify header in the first column without ruining the order of the other headers

Comment: Can I please get some help with this, would mean so much to me because I am really stuck

Comment: @abhilb, i marked it as answered. thank you so much.
I have a quick question. In on of the lines  I have  `SetData x="-goals" `and when I open the csv file I see `#NAME?`

Comment: @abhilb, I asked the question above because I checked my large csv file and saw that I have that problem. Question was asked here and seems like the code format was similar to the one in this question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753414/minus-sign-not-being-parsed-from-xml-to-csv?noredirect=1