# Adding to elements to a header

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

The code below  goes to the header names **Phones** and parses every element into csv files. This is done for every XML file in that folder. Meaning all the elements of FACTS from all those XML files are parsed into one single CSV file.

This is the code

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as cET
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

def phones_to_df(fname):
    tree = cET.parse(fname)
    return pd.DataFrame([{**{el.tag: el.text for el in list(phone)},
                          **{f'nuk_{k}': v for k, v in phone.find('nuk').items()}}
                  for phone in tree.iterfind('Phones')])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xmls = [f for f in Path('C:/Users/Desktop/Original/test').glob('*.xml')] 
    df = pd.concat([phones_to_df(xml) for xml in xmls])
    df.to_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/Original/all.csv")
```

This is how the XML file looks like

```
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Phones>
    <Date />
    <Prog />
    <Box />
    <Feature />
    <PR>1231</PR>
    <Set>234234</Set>
    <FD>23423</FD>
    <Reno>454</Reno>
    <Simple>dfasd</Simple>
    <Nr />
    <gt>6070106091</gt>
    <Reno>1233</Reno>
    <QW>3234</QW>
    <ER />
    <VR />
    <Use />
    <Dar>sdfsd</Dar>
    <age />
    <name1>sdfsfdfs</name1>
    <Sys>Itone</Sys>
    <aac>2014</aac>
    <time>02:00</time>
    <nuk name="This is some text" text_g="asadsdas" text_h="2">fsdfsfd3432fdf</nuk>
  </Phones>

</Data>
```

I’m struggling to implement a new feature into this code. I want to code to get element **PR** and element **Reno**  get them together with an **_** and parse them to column one with the header  named ** PLAN**

The output should look like this 
[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzPw3.jpg)

Comment: Your code has a flaw: since you have repeated tags (e.g. `'Reno'` appears twice) only the last one is stored in the dictionary, since keys in dictionaries are unique. Or maybe the repeated `'Reno'` tag is a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the nodes in `Phones` are unique, you can just adapt the dictionary you are building to create the dataframe adding the extra column you want:

```
def phones_to_df(fname):
    tree = cET.parse(fname)
    return pd.DataFrame([{'PLAN': f'{phone.find("PR").text}_{phone.find("Reno").text}',
                          **{el.tag: el.text for el in phone},
                          **{f'nuk_{k}': v for k, v in phone.find('nuk').items()}
                          }
                  for phone in tree.iterfind('Phones')])
```

Comment: thank you this is not really part of the question but I seem to get the first column with only zeros . I dont know how to get rid of it. This is how it looks https://ibb.co/80cC9Jd

Comment: @be1995 That is the row index of the dataframe, is added by `pd.to_csv`. To not add it, use the flag `index=False` like this: `df.to_csv("path/to/file", index=False)`.

Comment: marked it as answered. There is a similar question just like ths one but more complected . would appreciate if you can have a look at it Link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680887/reading-from-another-child-element-using-elementree/59681281#59681281