# Replace comma with semicolon when creating Csv Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a code that creates a csv file, when I first open it I everything is in one column so I have  to do the usual

Go to    Data and do the following. The data is then spplited into columns.

[image]

I work with Office 365, and recently I was told that if I change the commas with semicolons then when I open the newly created file Csv file, Excel will automatically open the file already separated into columns.

I’m asking for some advice here, since having to do this process for every created Csv file is really time consuming.

Looking for a way to alter my code so it does this automatically maybe instead of splitting columns with commas, do it with semicolons in this case. Just to try if this works out.

```
with open('created.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtxO4.png
```

Comment: Do you need `df.to_csv('created.csv', sep=';')` ?

Comment: @BigBen, in one of my computer when I open the file it is already separated into columns. On this other computer where I have office365 it doesn't show the csv file already in column

Comment: @jezrael, I'm not sure how would I change my current code to that. The code is this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/59680887/12325998

Comment: Yes. Microsoft is Micro!@#$ in this case: CSV stands for COMMA separated value, yet Excel doesn't recognise commas as separators by default, only semicolons... While open software like LibreOffice will recognise both the correct format (commas) and Excel's semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already want to transform an existing file you can do it like that:

```
with open('created.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f_in, open("outfile.csv", 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.split(",")
        line = ";".join(line)
        f_out.write(line)
```

In case you have already a dataframe you can do it like [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59770565/replace-comma-with-semicolon-when-creating-csv-dataframe#comment105684783_59770565) said in the comment with:

```
df.to_csv('created.csv', sep=';')
```

As mention in the comment you are already using the csv module to write your file. You have to change this line in your code:

```
writer = csv.writer(f)
```

to

```
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
```

As for me if I open a csv splitted with "," I have to that thing you described in your question. But if I open a csv splitted with ";" it's already in the right columns. 
This is (for Windows user at least) dependent on your **region** settings. This can be different for everyone dependent on your language settings.

You can check them here and also change it if you want:

https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/office-2013/excel-20132016-how-to-change-csv-delimiter-character/

Comment: thank you for your answer. This is my code https://stackoverflow.com/q/59680887/12325998. I would really want to inside the code there to have a csv file that is already in columns.

Comment: thank you that fixed it. Would really appreciate if you can have a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/59753414/12325998.    I'am dealing with the same problem . The code is the same as in the link I sent you in the comment above

Comment: @ebe what you can do is basically remove the operation character or you can add `'` before each input `hej;hej;-hej` --> `'hej;'hej;'-hej` I don't see another solution.

Comment: can you please give an answer on how to implement your approach [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753414/minus-sign-not-being-parsed-from-xml-to-csv)

Comment: @ebe in the other threads there are a lot of links in the comments who answer the same problem and have better / the same solution that I gave you.

Comment: would have still appreciated if you would have shown how to implement it in that code , but I also understand.

Comment: @ebe in your case you can do it like this: `row_data = ["'"+e for e in row_data] `

Comment: which line from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680887/reading-from-another-child-element-using-elementree) should I change to your suggestion ?

Comment: @ebe I think before you write it. But the rest you should figure out yourself or open a new question. Good luck

Comment: Hi I had to make a new question regarding this. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802151/minus-sign-not-parsed-while-conversion-in-python) I have  added the code and also which part of the code I want to modify. Would mean a lot of you can help me implement your approach there.